# Why is Git ignoring this directory that is not in .gitignore?

Tags: git, directory, gitignore

I'm having a strange problem with a directory being ignored even though it's not in `.gitignore`. To be absolutely sure, I've even deleted `.gitignore` but that didn't make a difference.

Basically I had a directory "CliClient", which after much refactoring was moved under a different directory. Now I've noticed that when this directory exists, git doesn't see it, but also cannot add it to the index, and cannot delete it.

See below:

**Checking that directory exists:**

```
$ ll CliClient/
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x  2 4.0K Nov  5 12:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 4.0K Nov  5 12:31 ..
```

**Just to test, try to add the directory:**

```
$ git add CliClient/
```

**No, it didn't do it:**

```
$ git status
On branch lerna_migration
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/lerna_migration'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

**So it's probably already added? So delete it:**

```
$ git rm -r CliClient/
fatal: pathspec 'CliClient/' did not match any files
```

So it's there, not in .gitignore, not in the index, but invisible to git. I've tried many things, including `git check-ignore`, but that didn't help.

Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Git doesn't track directories, only files. If the directory is empty, there are no files to track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git only tracks files. Directories aren't tracked as a "real" entity, but only in the sense of the location of a file. Since the directory is empty there's nothing for git to track there, so the `git add` call doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I wonder if they should print an error or warning instead of a no-op like now, but anyway I'll know now.